# Cannot find MessageMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager class while trying to configure websocket security in Spring Boot 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-websocket

I am trying to configure websocket security with Spring Boot 3, while using `spring-boot-starter-parent:3.0.4`, going by the `@EnableWebSocketSecurity` [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/socket/EnableWebSocketSecurity.html) which say that I should use the class `MessageMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager`, but I can't seem to import it, it is not where it should be according to its [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/messaging/access/intercept/MessageMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager.html).

Am I missing some dependencies or what is happening here?

Here is my pom.xml, maybe it helps.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    ... omitted project data ...
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I tried finding which dependency should bring it into the project, but as far as I see, it should come with `spring-boot-starter-security`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well I found this dependency and it was the one I needed

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-messaging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

now the class can be imported. I still find it strange that it is not included in `spring-boot-starter-security` as a default.

Answer (score 1):

For gradle:

```
implementation group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-messaging', version: '6.1.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add this dependency and retry ;

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Sure, I added this but it is still missing.

Comment: maybe do `invalidate cache restart`if you are using intellij, because `MessageMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager` class is under this dependency.

Comment: I did so but still the import statements `messaging` part is red and mvn clean install fails as well.

Comment: I used a jar search website and found out that I need `spring-security-messaging`. Now the class can be imported.